# Finding & terminating threads to shutdown application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to terminate the running threads to shutdown application.

After executing common application exit commands, there are a few threads are still running, so application won't shut down completely (console window is still open).

I use code snippets which create those threads, so I can't control these threads. To kill them I need to modify the code and make a running threads collection like thing (long way) or get the -still- running threads and terminate them gracefully.

Now, how can I get the alive threads list in C#?

Comment: You need to show us some code or share how these "threads" are being created;  what classes are being used to create the threads?  This would determine what properties/methods are available in the instances of the threads to determine how to shut them down properly and wait until they terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while creating threads, you can set `thread.IsBackground = true` which terminates process event when they are not "finished" (when all non-background threads are).

more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

Comment: He can't, he's using snippets :)

Comment: I just searched for "new Thread" + added "thread.IsBackround = true"  on everywhere...